# Detect the vulnerability in this PHP - file

Tags: php, security, xss

I have this link

> `http://example.com/example.php?link=<link>&title=<title>&bild=<picturelink>&named=<text>`

each term in <> stands for a variable, which could be changed by a mean - spirited attacker.

```
<named> = domain-name of <link>
```

This is the handling php file

```
<?php
if(strpos($_GET[named],"known.com")!==false or 
   strpos($_GET[named],"known2.com")!==false or 
   strpos($_GET[named],"known3.com")!==false)
{
echo '<div align="center"><a href=' . 
     $_GET[link] . 
     ' target="_blank"><img alt="' . 
     htmlentities(utf8_decode($_GET[title])) . 
     '"  title="' . htmlentities(utf8_decode($_GET[title])) . 
     '"  src=' . $_GET[bild] . 
     '  border=0></a></div><br><br><b>' . 
     htmlentities(utf8_decode($_GET[title])) . 
     '</b><br><br><a  href=' . 
     htmlentities($_GET[link]) . 
     ' target="_blank" style="color: grey;">Text <i>' . 
     htmlentities(utf8_decode($_GET[title])) . '</i> text ' . 
     htmlentities($_GET[named]) . '!</a><br>(text)';
}
else
{
echo 'not allowed';
}
?>
```

How can it be attacked and which changes to the php file do you recommend?

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Escape your data!!!

Any user input should not be able to be directly put into the HTML, or they can insert Javascript and steal sessions and what not.

Use something like this this:   `htmlspecialchars($_GET['link'])`

See also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Exploit_scenarios

Answer (score 1):

`http://example.com/example.php?link=></a><script>alert('Pwned');</script><a&title=blaba&bild=blabla&named=known.com`

This url produce following HTML:

```
<div align="center">
    <a href=></a>
        <script>alert('Pwned');</script>
    <a target="_blank">
        <img alt="blabla"  title="blabla"  src=blabla  border=0>
    </a>
</div>
<br><br>
<b>blabla</b><br><br>
<a  href=blabla target="_blank" style="color: grey;">Text <i>blabla</i> text known.com!</a><br>(text)
```

You can see a valid `<script>` tag in it

Comment: Thx. Due to those two previous tips this is already not working.

Answer (score 0):

When printing these variables, you should convert them to entities at all times. So, in this case, you forgot a few variables.

```
$_CLEAN = array();
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $_CLEAN[$key] = htmlentities($value);
}
```

instead of echo'ing $_GET, you should echo $_CLEAN

Comment: You should only escape your data for HTML when you actually need it for HTML!  Otherwise, you are just muddying up your data that you might need in a more raw form for something different later on.

Comment: Brad, please revise your post. My snippet clearly shows that the original values are still present in the global $_GET. The $_CLEAN array -> values are escaped, NOT the $_GET values :-) When printing values that are coming from an user, you should always escape these values, otherwise you are seriously vulnerable for XSS-injections..

Comment: I am well aware, and read your post just fine.  My comment was to clarify for the original poster, so that he didn't modify what you wrote to simply replace values in `$_GET`.

Comment: Ah, allright! My apoligies, I thought you misunderstood/disagreed with the snippet ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Edit:
Escape your Data from the Get Variables.

Comment: Read this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Exploit_scenarios

Comment: @Brad Okay thanks, changed my answer.